# Delphi - draw on desktop canvas and make screenshot

Tags: delphi, canvas, drawing

Hi i have this part of code:

```
var
dc: HDC;
oCanvas: TCanvas;
r: TRect;
```

r - left, right, top, bottom - from parameters..

```
DC := GetWindowDC(0);
oCanvas:=TCanvas.Create;  
ocanvas.Handle:=dc;

ocanvas.Pen.Color:=clblue;
ocanvas.brush.Color:=clblue;
ocanvas.Pen.Width:=9;
ocanvas.ellipse(r);
```

some painting code...
....

```
oCanvas.free;
releaseDC (handle,dc);
```

My goal is:  Draw something to a desktop and then make a screnshot of it with procedure (screenshot 10,10,p.witdth,p.height,bmp)  {p is Trectangle} and save to file.. It works great in 90% of cases, but **sometimes my ellipse disapearring before capturing the screen**, and saving to bitmap...

My screenshot procedure i used:

```
procedure Tform1.ScreenShot(X, Y, W, H: integer;
  var AShot: TBitMap);
var
   dc: HDC;
   lpPal : PLOGPALETTE;

  function TestRegion:boolean;
  begin
    Result:= (W<>0);
    if Result then
      Result:= (H<>0);
    if Result then
      Result:= (X>-1);
    if Result then
      Result:= (Y>-1);

    AShot:= TBitmap.Create;
    //AShot.PixelFormat:= pf24Bit;
    AShot.Width:= W;
    AShot.Height:= H;
  end;
begin
{test width and height}
  if not TestRegion then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid region to capture. Check input values.');

  {get the screen dc}
  dc := GetDC(0);
  if (dc = 0) then exit;

  {do we have a palette device?}
  if (GetDeviceCaps(dc, RASTERCAPS) AND RC_PALETTE = RC_PALETTE) then
  begin
     {allocate memory for a logical palette}
     GetMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
     {zero it out to be neat}
     FillChar(lpPal^, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)), #0);
     {fill in the palette version}
     lpPal^.palVersion := $300;
     {grab the system palette entries}
     lpPal^.palNumEntries := GetSystemPaletteEntries(dc, 0, 256, lpPal^.palPalEntry);
     if (lpPal^.PalNumEntries <> 0) then begin
         {create the palette}
         AShot.Palette := CreatePalette(lpPal^);
     end;
     FreeMem(lpPal, sizeof(TLOGPALETTE) + (255 * sizeof(TPALETTEENTRY)));
  end;
  {copy from the screen to the bitmap}
  BitBlt(AShot.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, W ,H, Dc, x, y, SRCCOPY);
  {release the screen dc}
  ReleaseDc(0, dc);
end;
```

Comment: Instead of drawing on the desktop and then take a screenshot you could draw on the screenshot after you've taken it.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That's exactly what I would recommend too. Painting to the desktop can get nasty, it tends to leave behind artifacts.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but size of screenshot depends on my drawing - and i can not decide the W x H of the screenshot , just after drawing - that's my problem

Comment: That makes no sense. The size of the desktop is the same before or after you draw on it. Capture the entire desktop, do whatever you want with it, and save some or all of the image you captured when you're finished drawing.

Comment: You can't expect to draw directly on the desktop. It's not yours. The shell owns it. So just give that idea up.

Comment: I know this might not be the best way but I wrote a small app which has a transparent form. Then  I draw on it. I use it to help people while doing remote assistance. If you do that then you are not interfering with the desktop at all and you will be able to get your dimensions before capturing but that might also be useless as you would most probably still need to capture the desktop area.

Comment: The reason for loss of your graphics is because you have no control of when Windows refreshes the desktop. It can happen on any Shell Notification. So heed the warnings of the above comments.

Comment: Thanks, i solved it as @KenWhite suggested , it works :)